# Closed hyperplanes on a normed space are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space. I'd like to show that all closed hyperplanes in $X$ are isomorphic.

**My attempt**

Let $H$ and $W$ be closed hyperplanes. We know $\dim(X/H)=\dim(X/W)=1$, therefore $(X/H)$ and $(X/W)$ are isomorphic. How to conclude that W and H are isomorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick $v^*\in X^*$ with $Ker(v^*)=V$. Then, if $v^*(v)\not=0$, $V$ is isomorphic to $X/[v]$. Namely, the maps
$$
x\mapsto x+[v], \quad x+[v] \mapsto x-\frac{v^*(x)}{v^*(v)}v
$$
are inverse isomorphism.

Pick $w^*$ and $w$ as above corresponding to $W$. There is $u^*\in X^*$ with $u^*(v)$ and $u^*(w)$ nonnull scalars. If $U=Ker(u^*)$ we have
$$
V\simeq X/[v]\simeq U \simeq X/[w]\simeq W.
$$

A quantitative study reveals that the Banach-Mazur distance from U to W is bounded by a universal constant (not depending of the Banach space $X$). Is the optimal constant known?